# Table with a multiple lines in a multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to recreate this table

[image: picture of table]

```
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|p{2cm}|c|c|}
\hline
& 
\multirow{1}{*}{Price at \\t=0}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Futrue ($t.t=1..1$) price} \\
\cline{3-4}
 &  & Event $u$ &Event $d$\\
\hline
Risk Asset & \textcolor{red}{\$A} & \$$uA$ &\$$dA$\\
\hline
Risk free Asset & \textcolor{red}{\$1} & \$$F$ &\$ $F$\\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: There is not really a need for a `\multirow` here. A simple `\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
& 
Price at 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Futrue ($t.t=1..1$) price} \\
\cline{3-4}
 & at t=0 & Event $u$ &Event $d$\\
\hline
Risk Asset & \textcolor{red}{\$A} & \$$uA$ &\$$dA$\\
\hline
Risk free Asset & \textcolor{red}{\$1} & \$$F$ &\$ $F$\\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}` should suffice.

Comment: TY! What about the row and column colors

Answer (score 2):

In order to get "Price at t=0"  to be displayed in two lines there is no need for `\multirow`. Just split the text into the two table rows which you nevertheless need for the header part of the last two columns.

Since you asked about the background colors, as well, I added a second example using `nicematrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
& 
Price at 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Futrue ($t.t=1..1$) price} \\
\cline{3-4}
 & t=0 & Event $u$ &Event $d$\\
\hline
Risk Asset & \textcolor{red}{\$A} & \$$uA$ &\$$dA$\\
\hline
Risk free Asset & \textcolor{red}{\$1} & \$$F$ &\$ $F$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc}[hvlines, rules/color=[gray]{0.35}, cell-space-limits=3pt]
\CodeBefore
\rowcolor{black!5}{1,2}
\columncolor{black!5}{1,2}
\rectanglecolor{black!15}{3-2}{4-2}
\Body
\Block{2-1}{}   &  \Block{2-1}{Price at\\ t=0} & \Block{1-2}{Future ($t.t=1..1$)\\ Price in} \\
                &                              & Event $u$    & Event $d$                    \\
Risk Asset      & \textcolor{red}{\$A}         & \$$uA$       &\$$dA$                        \\
Risk free Asset & \textcolor{red}{\$1}         & \$$F$        &\$ $F$                        \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw [black, thick] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```